# Interface Iterator already defined somewhere in Java?

Tags: java, interface, iterator

Is the interface `Iterator` already defined somewhere in java library (mind the terminology).
i.e.

What i am asking is that, say i have an arraylist, now i write.

```
Iterator itr= new Iterator();
```

but i never define anything like

```
public interface Iterator{  // all the methods };
```

Do i need to import some package where this iterator is already defined?

Let me take an example here:

```
class BOX implements Comparable {

    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    BOX(double l, double b, double h) {
        length = l;
        width = b;
        height = h;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return 2 * (length * width + width * height + height * length);
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return length * width * height;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object other) {
        BOX b1 = (BOX) other;
        if (this.getVolume() > b1.getVolume()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.getVolume() < b1.getVolume()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return 
        “Length:
        ”+length +
        ” Width:
        ”+width +
        ” Height:
        ”+height;
    }
} // End of BOX class
```

And here is my test class.

```
import java.util.*;

class ComparableTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList box = new ArrayList();
        box.add(new BOX(10, 8, 6));
        box.add(new BOX(5, 10, 5));
        box.add(new BOX(8, 8, 8));
        box.add(new BOX(10, 20, 30));
        box.add(new BOX(1, 2, 3));
        Collections.sort(box);
        Iterator itr = ar.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            BOX b = (BOX) itr.next();
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}// End of class
```

Now in class `ComparableTest`  should not it implement `interface iterator`  also, shall i not define an `interface iterator` that will contain all the methods. Also, where is the implementation of the iterator methods are?

I maybe confused alot, but kindly help!
thanks.

Comment: The methods of the `java.lang.Iterator` are implemented by the `ArrayList` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you mean [`java.util.Iterator<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

And no, you don't write:

```
Iterator itr= new Iterator();
```

... that could never work, given that it's an interface. Also, it's `Iterator`, not `iterator`, and your code should use `import`, not `Import` - Java is case-sensitive.

Instead, you write:

```
Iterator<Foo> iterator = list.iterator();
```

But no, `ComparableTest` doesn't need to implement `Iterator<E>` - why would it? It *uses* the `Iterator` interface, but it doesn't *implement* it.

Comment: now iterator is just an interface, but how does my list know, how to iterate... i.e. where is the implementation of all the methods of iterator?

Comment: @Karan: `ArrayList` handles that for you - it's up to the collection to decide how you iterate over it, not the caller. It's up to the caller what you *do* with it. (Btw, these are all generic types - you should be using them that way instead of using the "raw" types.)

Comment: ok it uses the interface, but somewhere the implementation has to be../? Where is that in this case?

Comment: @Karan, I think you need to read a book on Java and OOP basics.

Comment: @Karan: Yes, when you call `iterator` on the `ArrayList` (which implements `Iterable`) the `ArrayList` returns an implementation. You don't need to care what the implementation is - just that it implements the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The interface `Iterator` is defined in the package `java.util` in the standard API. You can use it because you have the line `import java.util.*;` in your code.

You do not have to implement it; it is implemented by an inner class of `ArrayList` which the method `ArrayList.iterator()` returns.

You can find out things like this by looking at the source code of the Standard API, which comes with your JDK in a file src.zip.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it is already defined. It is a built in Interface that comes in Package `java.util` and you need to import it like `java.util.Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous posts, it is unnecessary (given the current context) to use an Iterator. Instead, you should try java's "enhanced for loop":

```
for(BOX temp: box){
    //do something...
}
```